# why "ReferenceError: {fn} is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, jbox

I am trying to build a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/0ndf7ena/12/) to test some features of [jBox](https://stephanwagner.me/jBox/get_started), but when executing the code it complains about `askMe` not being defined. I do think that it is defined in my script which I also validated with JSLint, so I'm really struggling to get this working.

**HTML**:

```
<span onclick="askMe" ">Click me</span>
```

**JS**:

```
var jb;

function askMe() {
  console.log(jb);
  jb.Open({"confirmButton": "new confirm-text here!"});
};


$(function(){

    jb = new jBox(
    "Confirm", {
        "cancel":function() {$(document).trigger("event_no");},
        "cancelButton":"No",
        "confirm":function(){$(document).trigger("event_yes");},
        "confirmButton":"Yes",
        "content":"Do you like this sample?",
        "title":"Your choice, please!"
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: The problem with your fiddle is because you've told it to wrap the code in a load handler and are missing the `()` from the function call. Use `No wrap - in <head>` ( or `</body>`) instead - or better still use an unobtrusive event handler instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. That said, your code still doesn't work as `jb.Open() isn't a function`: https://jsfiddle.net/0ndf7ena/14/

Comment: Yup. you have the onclick set to `askMe` vs. `askMe()`, and in a fiddle it needs them to be global if you're going to call them that way. As Rory says, you'd be better to try an unobtrusive approach (attach your event listener in your javascript). And last, `jb.Open()` is not a function -- use `jb.open()` https://jsfiddle.net/eL5a4te4/

Comment: Thanks - both of you for useful input. Got it working now :) Rory, can you pls. post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just posting this so that the answer can be closed. Rory's comment about  the wrapping in jsfiddle really put me on the right track - I had never really understood this feature! (Yeah, embarrassing, I know.)
Additionally it had to be a function-call with proper casing, as snowmonkey pointed out.